# Cannot generated enumeration class using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I've a lot of difficulties generating some POJOs from an XSD (distributed as a standard that I don't have control and I cannot changed) using JAXB.  The problem seems to be related to the way certain types are defined in that XSD.  Below I've pasted a simple type defined in this XSD named TransactionCodeType which is a union of a token combined with an enumeration list of values, also defined as a token.

```
<xs:element name="TransactionContentDetails">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="TransactionIdentifier" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="TransactionCode" type="TransactionCodeType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:simpleType name="TransactionCodeType">
    <xs:union memberTypes="xs:token">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
                xs:enumeration value="Design E-Filing"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="Design B2B-Filing" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Design Information" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Design Identifier List" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Design List" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Design Opposition E-Filing" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Design Opposition Information" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Design Opposition Identifier List" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Representative Appointment" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Amendment Registered Design" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Amendment Application" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Convention Application" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Additional Application" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Subsequent Application" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Divisional Application" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Assignment Application" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Assignment Registered Design" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Request Certified Copies" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Request Extension Time" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Request Hearing" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Opposition First Extension" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Opposition Various Renewal/Extension of Registration Restoration" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Withdrawal" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Withdraw Application" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Withdraw Design" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Response Examination Report" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Statement Support" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Withdraw Service Request" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Request Publication" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Request Registration" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Offer Surrender" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Request Exclusion" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Request Conversion" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Duplicate Certificate" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Request Supply Documents" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Request Delayed Registration" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Request Accelerated Examination" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Expiry Notice" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Refusal Withdrawal Notification" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Division International Registration Notification" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Refusal Notification" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Providing Certificate To Holder" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Transmittal Application To IB" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Irregularities" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Invalidation Notification" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Cancellation Representative Appointment" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Application Receipt" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Notice Document By Design Formality Examination" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Notice Document By Design Substantial Examination" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Notice Document By Design Registration" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Notice Document By Trial Examination - Invitation" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Notice Document By Trial Examination" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Notice Document By Trial Examination - Decision" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Memo By Design Formality Examination" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Memo By Design Substantial Examination" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Memo By Trial Examination" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Memo By Trial Notice" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Memo By Trial Examination - Correction" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Accept Design Application Document" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Accept Design Applicant Document" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Accept Design Attorney Document" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Accept Design Withdrawal And Abandonment Document" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Accept Design Response Document" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Accept Design Submission Document" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Accept Design Amendment Document" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Accept Design Request For Inspection" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Accept Demand For A Trial" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Accept Trial Intermediate Document" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Inspection Accept Design Application Document" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Inspection Accept Design Applicant Document" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Inspection Accept Design Attorney Document" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Inspection Accept Design Withdrawal And Abandonment Document" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Inspection Accept Design Response Document" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Inspection Accept Design Submission Document" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Inspection Accept Design Amendment Document" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Inspection Accept Design Request For Inspection" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Inspection Accept Demand For A Trial" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Inspection Accept Trial Intermediate Document" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Inspection Notice Document By Design Formality Examination" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Inspection Notice Document By Design Substantial Examination" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Inspection Notice Document By Design Registration" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Inspection Notice Document By Trial Examination - Invitation" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Inspection Notice Document By Trial Examination" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Inspection Notice Document By Trial Examination - Decision" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Inspection Memo By Design Formality Examination" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Inspection Memo By Design Substantial Examination" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Inspection Memo By Trial Examination" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Inspection Memo By Trial Notice" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Certified Copy Notice Document By Design Formality Examination" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Certified Copy Notice Document By Design Substantial Examination" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Certified Copy Notice Document By Design Registration" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Certified Copy Notice Document By Trial Examination - Invitation" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Certified Copy Notice Document By Trial Examination" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Certified Copy Notice Document By Trial Examination - Decision" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Accept Document List" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Notice Document List" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Application Information" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Balance Sheet Reference" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Division Number List" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Record Licence" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Record Mortgagee" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Terminate Licence" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Discharge Mortgagee" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Change of Name" />
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:union>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Using JAXB, the output generated (see below) is translate as the basic type String in Java.  I'm using the latest version of maven-jaxb2-plugin from org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2. At some point, this is what I expected.  Therefore, I would like to be able to access from the Java code the list of possible values that are defined within the XSD.  But how ?  JAXB doesn't generated a enumeration class that defined all these values. I've searched on the web including under this site to find solutions; try some of the proposed solutions including the usage of bindings without any success.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "transactionIdentifier",
    "transactionCode",
})
public static class TransactionContentDetails implements Serializable  {

    @XmlElement(name = "TransactionIdentifier")
    protected String transactionIdentifier;
    @XmlElement(name = "TransactionCode", required = true)
    protected String transactionCode;

    public String getTransactionIdentifier() {
        return transactionIdentifier;
    }

    public void setTransactionIdentifier(String value) {
        this.transactionIdentifier = value;
    }

    public String getTransactionCode() {
        return transactionCode;
    }

    public void setTransactionCode(String value) {
        this.transactionCode = value;
    }
}
```

So, I’m looking to see if you have any ideas on how I could resolve that problem, i.e., being able to generate a Java enumeration class containing all these values.  As part of the solution, I don't want to have to redefined all these values within a binding file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can change your schema to add **name** then generate the pojo of Name "designEnum".

```
  <xsd:simpleType name="designEnum">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="Design1"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="Design2"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
```

// Enum

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
@XmlType(name = "designEnum")
@XmlEnum
public enum DesignEnum {

    Design1,
    Design1;

    public String value() {
        return name();
    }

    public static DesignEnum fromValue(String v) {
        return valueOf(v);
    }

}
```

Comment: he can't change the xsd!

Comment: Ah..missed that in question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like unions are not well supported https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_2_2_10-Defining-a-Type-Union.html

If you could modify the schema you could extract the enumerated anonymous simple type to a named type and then use in your code the Java enum generated for this new type....

Answer (score 0):

xsd restrictions aren't an enum, if you use enum you will have problem with marshalling. You can add a custom behavior to jaxb code generator and add validation on setTransactionCode method.

Look at this article https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Adding_behaviors.html

Answer (score 0):

The following enum is the one that cause this issue;

the value contains a slash "/":

```
<xs:enumeration value="Opposition Various Renewal/Extension of Registration Restoration" />
```